# Access ASP.NET Core 2.1 web app hosted on localhost from mobile device

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I create an out of the box asp.net core 2.1 web app with react.
When I run it, it hosts on localhost:(some port).
I want to access that on my mobile device.

I tried accessing it from localhost by adding the port to the Inbound Rules on Windows Defender Firewall.It didn't work so I wanted to change the ip address to 0.0.0.0:(some port) or to host it on my local IPv4 address by changing the lauchSettings.json and Program.cs by .UseUrls method. It didn't work, gave me an error that the app cannot run.
I tried using my external IP address which I got from asking "My ip address" in Google but that didn't help as well.

[image: Picture of Program.cs file]

[image: Picture of lauchSettings.js]

[image: Error when changing lauchSettings.js]

Comment: The default behavior of development servers is to not allow any connection but localhost. If you are using the 'run' button in visual studio, you're not going to be able to connect from anywhere but your local machine without some additional work or deploy it to an actual server.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I use this, maybe it can help

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseUrls("https://*:5566")
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

Note that for the latest .Net, you set the URLs in the launchSettings.json file as shown below:

[image: latest .Net version]

Make sure to enable the port 5566 in firewall. From the phone access https://your_comp_ip_address:5566/ it should work.
Change your_comp_ip_address to your computer ip address, you can check it from the CMD. Just run 'ipconfig' in the CMD

From Visual Studio, run the App itself, not IIS Express, select AppNamefrom the drop down, then press F5. Kindly Check all of these photos below:

[image: From The Drop Down, select the AppName to run it]

[image: Windows Firewall Ports, add a new Outbound Rule: Port, say give a range of 5560-5570]

[image: Check the IP address]

[image: Make sure when you run, a CMD is displayed, and check out the code https://*:5566]

[image: From your phone browser, enter the url correctly]

[image: And then, voila!!! Your Web App is running]

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work, no matter what I write in UseUrls. I think that launchSettings.json has a higher priority, but if a change something there it doesn't even run the project and displays the above error I've attached.I added the inbound rule of the port.

Comment: have you put https or http?

Comment: I have updated my answer for any user, beginner or advanced.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I just want to add to your answer that the phone should be on the same wi-fi as the pc hosting the web app.

Comment: Yeap, I forgot to mention that. Phone and computer should be on the same WiFi/ network. Happy Coding buddy

Comment: Though .net core api running on `192.168.0.4:5566`, still unable to connect from my android phone ... both laptop and mobile are in `same wifi network` ... however able to connect through emulator as in same computer

Answer (score 1):

localhost always points to the current device loopback address, so localhost on your pc points to itself and localhost on a phone points to itself as well. If your phone is connected to the same network as your pc you could launch the site on a specific local ip address instead of localhost and connect using the ipaddress. But I don't think it is possible to use IISExpress with anything other than localhost. You could use a different launch profile and just use kestrel directly with an ipaddress instead of using IISExpress.

If you use an android emulator on your machine then you could access the site via a special ipaddress that allows the emulator to connect to the pc, so if running at localhost:5566, from the emulator you would use http://10.0.2.2:5566

I'm not sure about other emulators for iphone etc, they may have different conventions.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, all you will have to do is replace `"localhost"` with a wildcard `*` (or with your local LAN IPv4 Address) in *Properties/launchSettings.json*:

```json
{
  // ...
  "profiles": {
    // ...
    "Moshoboga": {
      // ...
      // replace: "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000"
      "applicationUrl": "https://*:5001;http://*:5000"
    }
  }
}
```

Then navigate to your local ip in any browser on your LAN. Find this with [`ipconfig`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ipconfig) on Windows, or [`ifconfig`](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=ifconfig) on Unix/Linux

Answer (score 1):

For newer .NET Core (v6) just add your your IP url in `applicationUrl` property in `launchSettings.json` file like that:

`"applicationUrl":https://localhost:7001;http://localhost:7000;http://192.168.1.78:7000;https://192.168.1.78:7001"`

You can find out your current local IP address (IPv4) in cmd/powershell (Windows) by typing `ipconfig`