# HTTPS not available in localhost on mobile device

Tags: android, .net, http, mobile, https

How to get https on the localhost on my mobile device? When I start my .NET Core project on my PC there is https://localhost. But when I try to connect to localhost following these instructions: [Access ASP.NET Core 2.1 web app hosted on localhost from mobile device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53364145/access-asp-net-core-2-1-web-app-hosted-on-localhost-from-mobile-device) what I get is HTTP. Is generating and installing SSL certificate on IP address the only solution? Or maybe there is another way to check how push messages look like on mobile device?

Comment: Is your webserver running on your Android device that you use localhost? It is unclear how you try to connect to localhost too.

Comment: Trying to get to localhost on mobile device I type on URL bar: https://[ipdaress]:port. Then there is warning that connection is not secure. App is not deployed anywhere it works only locally.

Comment: Your pc is its own localhost. Your android device is its own localhost. Every device/pc/laptop/smartphone is its own localhost. It is unclear which device you have in mind if you only talk about localhost.